Double Slit experiment using a corrugated screen
If the experiment was to be performed using a corrugated screen, with a vertical zig-zag pattern, wouldn't that allow to examine the direction of each electron and determine where it came from?
To clarify: the screen would be folded to have alternating segments oriented in such a way so it wouldn't be possible for electrons coming from slit 1 to hit a segment oriented at slit 2, and vice-versa.

The electron is dumb, the EM field determines the path.
